# What is the music that plays during first cutscene in Hitman Absolution?

Tags: hitman-absolution, game-music-identification

I'm looking for the music that plays while Diana talks to Victoria in the first cutscene in *Hitman Absolution*. I can't find the name of to match that.

The background tune plays right when Diana says "a man will come"? It is also repeated at the end, when 47 views Diana and Victoria through the scope.

Can someone please tell me what is the name of the tune?

Comment: Its not on the OST?

Comment: Robotnik, no it is not, that was the first place I looked I even got the pause ambience from the menu and the cutscene I'm talking about but with the speech, in other words most likely someone ripped the sound off the cutscene and uploaded as an mp3.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking for the Prologue track, playing [here](https://youtu.be/qfmhgIC6AR4), but without a monologue on top of it? As far as I can tell, this simply doesn't exist. Exploring further, though.

Comment: That is exactly what i am looking for NGCaptainM, I guess if someone really liked the music and they were good with audio software they could take out the voices without compromising the quality, I tried but I am not good at that so the result was unsatisfactory.

Comment: I realize it is silly to look this hard for one soundtrack but it's just one of those tunes that you really like for some reason.